# Embedding SqlLocalDb in NSIS installer script

Tags: nsis, localdb

I'm trying to embed sqllocaldb into my installer script.

the installer so far is working. The application gets installed.
But the user should be asked if he wants to install sqllocaldb. If I say yes the installer just throws the sqllocaldb.msi to the installed dir and does not execute it.

I followed the script on the nsis page but..

```
Section "SqlLocaldb"
 SetOutPath $INSTDIR\Prerequisites
 MessageBox MB_YESNO "Would you like to use a local db Server?" /SD IDYES IDNO endSqlLocaldb
    IfFileExists 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe' endSqlLocaldb beginSqlLocaldb
    Goto endSqlLocaldb
    beginSqlLocaldb:
    File "SqlLocaLDB.msi"
    ExecWait '"SqlLocaLDB.msi" /i "$INSTDIR\Prerequisites\SqlLocaLDB.msi"'
    endSqlLocaldb:
SectionEnd
```

Any ideas what i'm missing out here?

Answer (score 0):

This is old but: The execwait should be

```
ExecWait  'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\Prerequisites\SqlLocaLDB.msi"'
```